# Idea cannot resolve java.sql.* symbol,notice cannot import

Tags: import, package

the idea cannot resolve java.sql.* symbole,below is i find problem.i install jdk with 1.8.0_181.

i have already tried using below actions. file->invalidate cache /restart,But the problem still exists

[it is said the unused import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUlat.png)

[the rt.jar package in idea explorer,the jdk path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUlat.png)

[the rt.jar package in winrar explorer, the jdk path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUlat.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mysql dependency to your project. If you are using the maven project, gradle ,sbt use this link and add it into your project.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.12

If you are not using any of this above download mysql-connector-java jar manually and add it in class path. 
you can download jar from here https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: thanks,but the problems still exists,so, i can build the project,the problem is the rt.jar package,there have the difference between idea jdk explorer and winrar explorer.i set the same jdk path.